# PostgreSQL connection error in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

i am getting below error while trying to connect my postgreSQL local database. Please help on this problem as i am new to this concept:
Code and error details:[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the inner exception (the one which caused the outer one) is saying that it cannot load assembly.

Try adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` to you packages (in VS, click "add package" in menu on the right after right click).

Comment: @satish - Great! Wouldn't you mind marking the answer as correct, so that others will immediately see it? Thank you!